# How to have numbered scale with Seekbar (Android)?

Tags: android, numbers, customization, android-seekbar

I am trying to customise Seekbar. I need Seekbar  like :

[image: Seekbar]

How do I add numbered scale to Seekbar as shown in image above?

I have been able to make  custom thumb and custom progress drawable simply by using their vectors, in XML, as:

```
android:thumb="@drawable/custom_seekbar_thumb"
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar_progress"
android:splitTrack="false"
```

But I have not been able to use the numbered scale as shown in the image.

Some answers on stack overflow say about how to draw numbers above/below Seekbar, but I couldn't find any information on how to draw the vertical line (|) below each number.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: May be this sample suitable to you 
https://www.informaticscentre.co.uk/blog/implementing-a-seekbar-with-stepped-intervals-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

There is a method [`setTickMark`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar#setTickMark(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) and xml attribute `android:tickMark` that  can be used to draw vertical lines. But there are two problems. The first one is it is only available in api 24+. The second one is that all the ticks would be the same and in your design they are different.

Unless you find a library that does exactly what you need, your best option is to create a custom view by subclassing/copying `SeekBar` and customizing the `onDraw` method.